# How to show window forms only together in C#?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have one main window that produces another forms that also produces child forms, so while the application is working, I may be having few opened forms.
That's fine, until I choose, for example, a browser in taskbar, so, the application is remaining on background, but if I get the window back, I only see one of the having windows while the rest is remaining minimised.
But I want the app to open forms only together: main window is on background and child forms are on front. 
Can I use some property that let me show forms only in described way?

I use Windows Forms and DevExpress.

Comment: Has this question been solved?

Answer (score 1):

What you are likely looking for is called [MDI child forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-mdi-child-forms).